# Facebook Ads targeting by mobile device?

Tags: facebook, advertising, ad-targeting

Facebook ads allow you to target mobile device users like so:

[image]

Does this mean users who use Iphone regularly or users who are **currently** using Iphone to browse Facebook?

Answer (score 1):

***It's pretty self explanatory...*** All Mobile Devices by Operating allows you to target your Facebook ads on certain devices, for example if you have a iPhone/iPod/iPad app then you would advertise that on iOS, not Android or Windows. If you have research that tells you more people on Android are likely to buy into your services or products then you can target those users.... Generally you shouldn't need to select which devices unless you have 'PROVEN' stats that says otherwise.

Comment: But why do Facebook let you choose between 'Desktop Newsfeed' and 'Mobile Newsfeed' afterwards? What if I chose 'All iOS devices' for example and then 'Desktop Newsfeed', wouldn't that leave me with 0 targets?

Comment: No, it'd mean that All iOS and desktops would work, while android and other phones wouldn't.

Comment: Meaning if I picked 'All iOS devices' and 'Desktop Newsfeed', it will show on both desktops and iphones. But if I don't pick 'All iOS devices', and only pick 'Desktop Newsfeed', it will only show on desktop? Sorry I'm confused.